# Javascript: Detect if Internet Explorer sent the mixed http on https page message

Tags: javascript

I have no choice but to use a http resource to deliver content on a https page.

I want to detect if Internet Explorer displayed the 'mixed http/https' message/prompt, so I can display a message to inform the user that this content will not show w/o accepting http content on https page.

Looking for a function to detect.

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot better to just ensure that the problem doesn't happen at all?  Why should somebody believe a website that tells them that a security warning should be ignored?

Comment: Solution: Don't use resources served over HTTP on a page served over HTTPS.

Comment: Just make the whole page HTTP -- same level of security.

Comment: Why use a secure page, when you can't deliver secure content anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, whether or not that appears should only depend on the version of IE and if there's actually mixed content.
So in theory, you could just detect if it's a version of IE which does that, and then display a message prior to making the request that the user must accept it for the site to work.